# Does Cordova (PhoneGap) save pages inside the app?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap

I'm new to Cordova(PhoneGap) and it is not clear for me if the result built package includes the html/js/css files or if I need to have a server hosting it?

I would like to have the html/js/css files updated automatically when I change them, would that be possible in Ionic+Cordova approach?

Basically I want the app to be able to work offline but to update its contents whenever there is a new version available. What would be the best approach to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all the HTML/CSS/JS is bundled into your apk/ipa file as documented [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/overview/), you don't need to have a server hosting it.

As far as the updates go, one option would be to release your app via Microsoft AppCenter, then you can use their [CodePush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/codepush/) functionality to perform updates.

Comment: Thanks, that is a very nice answer. So there is no know way to do something like accessing the page from a web server and caching them instead of having them bundled into the app?

Comment: You could do something like that - load a partial HTML page and save it to a cache. Then when you navigate to that page in your app, you could read the file and use JQuery to dynamically update a <div> with the contents